# Can i run C code on dalvik

Tags: android, android-ndk, dalvik

Can i run **C code on dalvik VM** on android ?

VM runs byte codes, but I need run  c-code on dalvik-VM for myApps. is it possible??

Answer (score 12, accepted):

First of all, the **Dalvik VM** can only run (his own format of) java bytecode.

If you need to run C code on Android, you'll have to use the [Android NDK](http://developer.android.com/sdk/ndk/index.html), write your C code, cross-compile it, and then you will be able to run it on your android platform.

If you need to use this code from a Android application, you will need to create a [JNI interface](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Native_Interface) to bind your C code to java ([as described in the examples of the NDK](http://developer.android.com/sdk/ndk/overview.html#samples)), then your java application running on the dalvik vm will call some java libraries that will call your C code (as a standard library).

Comment: More precisely, dalvik vm doesn't run java bytecode at all. It uses it's own bytecode format.

Comment: @JesusFreke : right, I edited my answer to avoid Oracle to launch an army of laywers against me ;)

Answer (score 1):

You should start here: http://developer.android.com/sdk/ndk/index.html

Answer (score -2):

Yes, using NDk you can run C code in android VM.